# ActiveMQ durable subscriber with PooledConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, connection-pooling, spring-integration

I am trying to implement a scenario where I have to create multiple durable subscribers in the same application. I want to use spring default messages listener container with ActiveMQ pooled connection factory where "maxConnection" specified to the required number of connections.

But I was going through some posts which are saying **not** to use pooling for durable subscriber :

http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/durable-topic-subscriber-using-spring-and-atomikos-td3209848.html 
http://osdir.com/ml/java.activemq.user/2005-05/msg00141.html

And I have also seen lot of posts recently about this. So my question is :
Should a client use the above specified configuration (pooledConnectionFactory with maxConnection specified for multiple durable subscriber) in an application. OR durable subscriber are not supposed to be used with pooling connection factory ?

What is the correct way to configure this type of test cases?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 2):

It is generally unnecessary to use any kind of pooling/caching with a listener container because the connection/session is long-lived. Caching/pooling provides major benefits when connections or sessions are short-lived and repeatedly created/destroyed (such as when sending messages). The listener container keeps its session(s) open for extended periods (depending on configuration). If you configure the container to only handle a limited number of messages per session, you can use Spring's `SingleConnectionFactory` (a separate one per container) to avoid the overhead of creating a new connection for each session.

Further, with durable subscriptions, the `clientId` is set on the connection, so you really don't want some other consumer to grab a pooled connection that has already had its `clientId` set to some other value.

Comment: Thanks gary. Can I use ActiveMQConnectionFactory (one factory for each container) ?    Also, what can be the possible cases for durable subscriber when using pooledConenctionFactory with maxConnection can break ?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand your second question. I explained the issue with pooling in the answer.

Comment: "The listener container keeps its session(s) open for extended periods (depending on configuration)." What are those configurations, Can you point me to those configurations ?

Comment: See the [Javadocs - specifically `maxMessagesPerTask` and `receiveTimeout`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setMaxMessagesPerTask-int-).